# How to use an arrayformula to calculate balance on each line

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a Google sheet which has two columns. Column F has a numeric value in it and I want column G to contain the value of column G in the previous row plus the value of column F in the current row, basically a running total.

I'm trying to use an array formula to do the calculation and it works for the first couple of rows but after that Column G contains the same value as Column F.

The formula I'm using is:

```
=arrayformula(F3:F10+G2:G9)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Why can't you just anchor your sum "from" cell with an absolute reference in row $2 or $3 or wherever it starts in your spreadsheet (which you should post, at least a screenshot) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, nothing should not use its own output as input. Iterative calculation would be required, and that's a trap-laden path to be avoided whenever there's an established alternative. In this case, the usual approach to a Running Total is MMULT and some garnishing.

If your data starts in F2, put this in G2:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F10,
  MMULT(
    TRANSPOSE((ROW(F2:F10)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(F2:F10)))*F2:F10),
    SIGN(F2:F10)),
  IFERROR(1/0)
))
```

Or, slightly more opaque, but able to cope with negative values:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F10,
  MMULT(
    TRANSPOSE((ROW(F2:F10)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(F2:F10)))*F2:F10),
    IF({F2:F10}<>0,1,0)),
  IFERROR(1/0)
))
```

Comment: This is likely overkill when the OP, from my reading of the problem, would be satisfied with a simple SUM(F$2:F…)

Comment: Granted. I thought the same, but people seemingly never come back, so I always write with other future readers in mind. I was shooting for the generalized approach, while musing whether perhaps the asker's "…I'm trying to use an ARRAYFORMULA…" was to reapply a simplified question to bigger, badder situations. Cheers.

Comment: I was originally using SUM but the spreadsheet in question often has rows inserted into ti and I got tired of duplicating the formula.  As I understand it, arrayformulas automatically handle inserted lines as long as they fall into the specified ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the MMULT tip, I wasn't aware of that.  I will give it a try and accept that solution if it works for me.

Comment: Nice tool for anyone's belt, whether we can best use it here or not. For more info, I found a nice [Ben Collins writeup](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/running-total/)/video that details its usage almost exactly as I used it. Nothing worse than maintaining someone else's indecipherable spaghetti formula when requirements inevitably change. And thanks for "coming back", ha.

Comment: Works great. I used the second formula since I need to deal with negatives

Answer (score 1):

a slight alternative would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F; 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(F2:F)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(F2:F)))*F2:F); 
 SIGN(F2:F)^2); IFERROR(1/0)))
```

[image: 0]